# Node Express 3x socket IO testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I try to add socket IO to my project but I didn't manage to make it work.

my app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

    var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});


  //IO Config

var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('makealert');
});
```

my views:

```
extends layout

script(type='text/javascript' src='../node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js')

script(type='text/javascript'
  var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('makealert', function () {
      alert('Boom');
  });
)

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

my route:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

I have 2 problems:
-first what's the way to find socket.io.js (in a jade view)
-second, is my app.js OK ?
-thrid, my console said:

> SyntaxError:
>   Node/thrid_app/demo-express/views/index.jade:5
>       3| script(type='text/javascript' src='../node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js')
>       4|
>
> > 5| script(type='text/javascript'
> >         6|   var socket = io.connect();
> >         7|   socket.on('makealert', function () {

Ty for yours helps

Comment: Hi, just after I find this and it works ... So I look alone for issue and I post for some people who need too.

[Github project][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/naholyr/node-chat-socketio-handshake

Comment: Just a suggestion. I would use EJS instead of Jade . To prevent parsing errors.

Comment: `socket.io` client code is at `/socket.io/socket.io.js` (so you don't need to include `/node_modules/` etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have mentioned is due to syntax error in `jade`

change this line

```
script(type='text/javascript'
  var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('makealert', function () {
      alert('Boom');
  });
)
```

to

```
script(type='text/javascript')
  var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('makealert', function () {
      alert('Boom');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Some mistakes in your code, also you seem to be using old jade syntax.

1. You are missing a comma in `script(type='text/javascript' src='../')`. It should be `script(type='text/javascript', src='../')`
2. Since jade 0.31, `script` must be used as `script.` or `script(...).`. Likewise for `style`.
3. Your last script tag in view is closed incorrectly

   ```
   script(type='text/javascript'
   ...
   )
   ```

   Should be like this

   ```
   script(type='text/javascript')
   ...
   ```

Comment: I abort this, ty for help but seems too deep for me.